# multiple a variable with number and adding the result again to the variable is returning wrong result

Tags: javascript

```js
function calculateAmount(val) {
  var price = val;
  if (quantity >= 100 && quantity < 1000) {
    var divobj = document.getElementById('discount');
    divobj.value = 20;
    var divobj1 = document.getElementById('total');
    var total = ((20 / 100) * parseInt(price)) + parseInt(price);
    divobj1.value = total;
  }
}
```

For example if enter the quantity to be 100 then the output return is 10020 instead 100+20 = 120

Comment: You have an error in the code, *quantity* is not declared or otherwise created. But assuming that it should be *price*, then likely the issue is that *price* (and hence *val*) is a string, not a number. In multiplication, division and subtraction it will be coerced to a number, but not addition, the other value will be coerced to string (hance `100 + "20" = "10020"`.

Comment: parseInt(price) use it .

Answer (score 0):

```
var price = val;
```

because the val is a string:

```
var price = +val;
```

please test this code, I hope this code works

```
divobj.value = 20;
```

please delete above line code:

```
var total = ((divobj.value / 100) * parseInt(price)) + parseInt(price);
```

and use above line code instead of use below code:

```
var total = ((20 / 100) * parseInt(price)) + parseInt(price);
```

Comment: Thanks Abbas! It's working perfectly!

Comment: Hi Abbas, if I need to use discount instead 20 in var total, how to do that?

function calculateAmount(val) {
  var price = val;
  if (quantity >= 100 && quantity < 1000) {
    var divobj = document.getElementById('discount');
    divobj.value = 20;
    var divobj1 = document.getElementById('total');
    var total = ((20 / 100) * price) + price;
    divobj1.value = total;
  }
}

Comment: I Edit my answer, please check for get your answer, and then, if possible, choose my answer as the correct answer, Thanks @ArunkumarSubbiah (-;